# OpenCart - Remove Option Value

Tags: opencart

I wish I knew where to find the position that makes the backend OpenCart Remove Option Value-for product / option - table

Comment: I'm not quite sure I do understand Your question... Could You, please, be more descriptive?

Comment: Is it the case that your options gets deleted from the product when you update the product from product update page?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean which file options get deleted and re-generated when you edit a product, the file is `admin/model/catalog/product.php` and the method is the `editProduct()` method. You'll notice that there's these two lines in there

```
$this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_option WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");
$this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_option_value WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try setting max_input_vars value in php.ini to 2000 and restart apache. This seem to fixed my issue where option values were deleted even when only product name was updated from product update page.